# Forwarding teams channel messages to another teams channel

Tags: microsoft-teams

I'm a member in a MS Teams channel which sends some notification messages, is there's a way to automatically forward these messages from that channel to another channel of my own.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with programming.

Comment: I'm looking for an automated way to do it. so if you have a code that can do that go ahead and share it.

Comment: Which language are you using ? Which automation framework ? Which issue are you facing ? What have you tried so far to solve the issue ? We're missing a few information here, in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you have a look at [Automate with Microsoft](https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/)

Accept the question if this helps you but please read the docs of Power Automate carefully :)